# How to move a node for a given time?

Tags: swift, sknode

I wonder how to animate a node to which I assign a few seconds until next action takes place.

For example, if a button is pressed, a node begins to move for three seconds, and after the three seconds pass away, a picture or text appears on the screen.

Should I use **NSTimer** and **NSTimerInterval**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this fairly simple approach that will help you to manage animation. This animation will take 3 seconds and at the end it will execute a completion handler.

```
    UIView.animateWithDuration(3.0, animations: { () -> Void in
       //animate object here
    }) { (state: Bool) -> Void in
       // hide animated object here
    }
```

Comment: Sorry for failing to mention accurately, I want to handle a SpriteNode, so UIView does not seem to work. How would I be able to do? Thanks for your response by the way!

Comment: Add this tag to the question pls